# How to make synchronous chain call with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have an action1 and action2 methods. action1 method creates a project structure and action2 method fills this structure with data. So first I need to call action1 and when it completes I need to call action2.

Is there any way to make synchronous chain call?

```
startPoint(){

    action1();
    action2();

}



action1(){
   //create a project structure
   return "completed";
}

action2(){
   //fill project structure with data
   return "completed";
}
```

Comment: What about `promises` if its one time execution?

Comment: @ShashankVivek Can you give an example how to call this simple methods with promises?

Comment: Angular2 doesn't support synchronous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an example.

```
action1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // do something
        resolve(<your return value>);
    });
}
action2() {
    // Do something
}

action1().then((res) => {
    action2();
}).catch(() => {
    // error case when reject is called
});
```

Alternatively you could just `return Promise.resolve(<value>);` in action1 and you can also use the `reject()` method in your promise in case of an error.

Comment: I was abt to answer :D :P

Comment: @Fussel How can I check if return value is Promise or not? I mean var returnvalue = action1();  if(returnvalue == Promise){......}

Comment: @hellzone : https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/ . For ref.